# Powershell csv calculate total sum

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, outlook, office365

I am currently working on powershell. Powershell is new for me so its kind of hard to figure out this one.

I have three headers in my csv files.

Headers include: Name, MessageCount and Direction.

Names are email addresses and those addresses are all the same. Direction have "Inbound" and "Outbound". MessageCount are bunch of diffrent numbers:

[Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYMbM.png)

I want to calculate those number so i get "Inbound" and "Outbound" Totals and emails on those rows.

I am trying to foreach loop out MessageCount and calculate those together it will only give me output like this :

[MessageCount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl4KM.png)

Comment: Take a look at [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.1). It'll make your life easier for this task.

Comment: And please do not post pictures of code or console output (or links to pictures of code) . Instead post it as text formatted as code. Thanks in advance.  ;-)

Comment: I have tried that but it will put those all information in one huge lane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$data = Import-Csv "path-to-your-csv-file";

$data | group Name 
      | select Name, 
          @{n = "Inbound"; e = { 
            (($_.Group | where Direction -eq "Inbound").MessageCount | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum } 
          }, 
          @{n = "Outbound"; e = { 
            (($_.Group | where Direction -eq "Outbound").MessageCount | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum } 
          }
```

#### Code explanation

`group Name` groups results by property `Name` - in this case, email address. More [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object)

`select` allows select property from object or create custom with `@{n="";e={}}`. More [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)

`($_.Group | where Direction -eq "Outbound").MessageCount` gets data from the group, searches for rows with `Direction` equal to `Outbound` and then gets the `MessageCount` from found rows.

`Measure-Object -Sum` takes array and creates object with properties ie. `sum` of values in array, so we get sum of `MessageCount` and return as custom property in object.

Comment: I'd recommend to indent your code to make it better readable and I'd recomend to write your code a little more verbose to make it easier to understand ... especially for beginners. Thanks in advance. ;-)